# Show/hide input in html form

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the second password input only to show after the user starts typing into the first input. Also, is there are way to either "require" them both or none at all?

```
<form name="signUpForm">
    ...

    <input ng-modal="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
    <input ng-show="password.$dirty" class="animate-show animate-hide" type="password" placeholder="password (again)">
</form>
```

Comment: `ng-modal` must be `ng-model`. Your input must have a name ("password" for example), and the correct way to access its dirty flag is to use `signupForm.password.$dirty`.

Comment: @Jackson, the angularjs docs show good examples here: [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) also see the answer i posted below which uses `$valid` and `required`. GL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

password has no property like $dirty but form controller has that one. So first of set name of input then you can access form controller with it

```
<form name="signUpForm">
...

    <input name="passwordNameAttr" ng-modal="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
    <input ng-show="signUpForm.passwordNameAttr.$dirty" class="animate-show animate-hide" type="password" placeholder="password (again)">
</form>
```

for dynamic require you can use **ng-required**. Just put an expresion on it and depends on condition your fields will be required or not...

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not animating but at least my extra input shows/hides now.

Answer (score 1):

another example using `ng-show` `$valid` `required` for input fields ..

html:

```
<form name="signUpForm">
   <input name="firstPassword" ng-model="first.password" type="password" placeholder="password" required>
   <input name="secondPassword" ng-show="signUpForm.firstPassword.$valid" ng-model="second.password" type="password" placeholder="password (again)" required>
</form>
```

working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vj5evgyw/2/